# What does 'take a shower' or 'shower' mean?

Tags: meaning, light-verbs

There are two sentences below:

1. She took a shower in the bathroom.
2. He showered in the bathroom.

What is the difference between 'take a shower' and 'shower' in meaning?

Answer (score 5):

There is very little difference in meaning; they are usually just two different ways to express the same thing: someone performed the act of showering.

"She showered in the bathroom" could mean that she *regularly* or *routinely* showered in the bathroom; "She took a shower in the bathroom" means that she performed one act of showering in the bathroom.

*Take a shower* is slightly less formal than *shower*.

---

The construction **"take a shower"** uses *take* as what's called a *light verb* in English.  A light verb is one that doesn't really carry any meaning by itself, but is used in conjunction with a noun to create a phrase that has meaning.  Usually, the light verbs in English are *do*, *take*, *make*, or *have*.

For example,

- take a shower = shower
- take a walk = walk
- take a rest = rest
- have a smoke = smoke (a cigarette, pipe, etc.)
- do a trick = perform a trick
- make a mistake = do something that is an error

References:

- [Light verbs](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/lightverbterm.htm)
- [Full-coverage Identification of English Light Verb Constructions](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/I13-1038)

Answer (score 3):

> They both get wet who take a shower and shower.
>
> They stand as though in driving rain
>
> For some variable fraction of an hour.
>
> Most lather, rinse; some lather, rinse, again.

Comment: I may have to create some extra IDs to vote this up. +1 is not enough

Comment: @PerryW That idea is all wet. Surely it is more practical to simply shower TRomano with praise?

Comment: While maybe not quite up to [The Greatest SE Answer, Ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), it's heading in the right direction. I actually had a T Shirt made up of that one...

Comment: @PerryW. I may descend into madness yet and give that answer a run for its money, as there is always the definite article to be considered.